# Searching for specific user group membership with an exact match

Tags: text-processing, grep

A user has multiple group memberships that contain spaces. Example:

- mydomain\staff
- mydomain\staff admin
- mydomain\staff super

User groups can be returned using:

```
id -Gn username | grep -i -o '\bstaff\b'
```

This unfortunately returns a hit if the user is a member of "mydomain\staff admin" or "mydomain\staff super", but not "mydomain\staff". How can I search for just the "mydomain\staff" group membership?

---

As requested, example output from

```
id -Gn username
```

is as follows (all one line):

> mydomain\staff mydomain\staff admin mydomain\staff super mydomain\some other group

Comment: `grep -i -o '^staff$'`

Comment: So the output of `id -Gn username` is something like, `bob admin staff dudes staff admin`? - if there's no separator, you can't return just staff?

Comment: Annoyingly, I have domain and a backslash to compete with as well (which wasn't in the question originally). Anchoring is not working until I can figure out the backslash match too.

Comment: Please show us the output of `id -Gn username` in your specific case.

Comment: Note that group names are case sensitive, you don't want `-i` here.

Comment: Escaping the \ is just \\\

Comment: Is that cygwin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `id -Gn` output is space delimited, you can't use that.

The GNU implementation of `id` since coreutils 8.22 has a `-z` option to output the list nul-delimited instead of space-delimited, so you could do (with GNU `grep` which you seem to be using already):

```
id -Gzn username | grep -Fxz 'mydomain\staff'
```

Or:

```
id -Gzn username | grep -z '\\staff$'
```

For `staff` in any *domain* (whatever that is).

Otherwise, if you have a `getent` command, you could take the problem in reverse:

```
staff_members=$(getent group 'mydomain\staff' | cut -d : -f 4-)
case ",$staff_members," in
  (*,username,*) printf '%s\n' 'username is member of mydomain\staff'
esac
```

Comment: As simple as -z *bangs head against wall*. Code blindness. Thanks, kudos.