# Aliases for sysadmins only in script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

There are several aliases/scripts I'd like to have available only to sysadmins. I know I can put the scripts in /usr/sbin. As for the aliases, I could add those after creating the user account manually:

```
#as root
adduser username
passwd username
usermod -aG wheel username
cd /home/username
nano .bashrc
if [ -f /path/to/file ]; then
  . /path/to/file
fi
```

But I'd rather have a file with those aliases that will be sourced in the sysadmin's .bashrc without me having to manually edit each .bashrc file. Suggestions, or do I simply need to do it the manual route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your distribution may have an /etc/profile that looks for files in /etc/profile.d; if so, place a file there that sets up those aliases for members of the wheel group. On a Debian system, the pertinent code is:

```bash
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

For bash, you would just need to name it with a `.sh` extension; for example:

### /etc/profile.d/admin-aliases.sh

```
# set up admin-only aliases if the user is a member of the wheel group
if id -Gnz "$LOGNAME" | grep -qxz wheel
then
  alias youralias=yourcommand
fi
```

The `id | grep` solution was borrowed from [Stéphane Chazelas' solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/256337/117549) to [Searching for specific user group membership with an exact match](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/256330/117549) . The idea is to see if the current user is a member of the wheel group.  `id -Gnz` asks for the list of groups (`-G`) by name (`-n`) in a null-separated list. That is then piped to `grep`, whose flags are:

- `-q` -- don't output any matches, just set the return code to success or failure
- `-x` -- require the entire "line" to match, so we don't get a false-positive if the user is a member of a group named `flywheel`
- `-z` -- interpret the input as a null-terminated list of "lines"

Answer (score 2):

If you really want scripts to be only runnable by sysadmins then the simplest thing to do is creating a directory which is only readable by the sysadmin group, and putting the relevant secrets in there.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to /etc/bash.bashrc:

```
if id -G | egrep "(^| )$(getent group wheel | cut -d: -f3)( |\$)" > /dev/null; then
    # set your aliases here
fi
```